# Wrapping async cycle in Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to do something like:

```
console.log("start spinner!");
for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; ++i) {
     var filename = modules[i].filename;
     $.get('./views/templates/'+ filename ).done(function(data){
           modulesTemplates.push(data);  
           console.log(data);
      }).fail();
}
```

How do I do for having a callback or wrapping this whole cycle in a promise?
I tried with bluebirdjs, something like:

```
Promise.all([ modulesTemplates ])
      .then(function(data){
           console.log(course.modulesTemplates);
           loadView('home.html');
           console.log("stop spinner!");
});
```

But it doesn't work. Am I missing something or is it a better way of doing this?

The sequence of the console.logs:

> start spinner!
>   [] 
>   stop spinner!
>   tempalte 1
>   template 2

Comment: Do you want all the requests to be concurrent (at the same time) or sequential (one after the other)?

Comment: sequential to load the templates in the correct order, because I want to load then in a linear way

Comment: You an load them in the correct order but still make the requests concurrently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bluebird, assuming the requests can be in flight at once, you can do something like:

```
console.log("Start Spinner");
Promise.map(modules, function(module){
    return $.get('./views/templates/' + module.filename);
}).then(function(modulesTemplates){
    // module template is a list of all the templates loaded here
    // this code will be reached after all are loaded, for example
    // modulesTemplates[0] is the first template.
    console.log("Stop Spinner");
});
```

Comment: awesome! thanks, I guess that .map() applies better than the .all()